# smwebmail and ISAPI extension during restore backup

Tags: windows, plesk

Hi i want to restore backup in Plesk Windows and get these errors

Warning: 
The PHP handler 5 ISAPI extension (id=isapi-5) is not available. Instead, Plesk will use 7.2.5 FastCGI application (id=fastcgi-7.2) for the following websites: ####

Warning: 
The webmail service smwebmail is unavailable. It will be replaced with horde for the following objects: ####

how i can enable ISAPI?
how i can install smwebmail?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to restore the backup on a newer server with a different configuration.

PHP 5 as an ISAPI extension is actually PHP version 5.2, which is no longer supported by PHP community. It is recommended to modify the website code to make it compatible with newer PHP versions. The oldest supported PHP version at the moment is 5.6.

If you still want to use PHP 5.2 ISAPI, you can add to any Plesk version except Plesk Onyx 17.8 in **Tools & Settings > Updates & Upgrades** or via a single line in CMD:

```
C:\>"%plesk_bin%\ai.exe" --select-release-current --install-component php5
```

As for `smwebmail`, you should have SmarterMail installed on the server and configured in Plesk. I suggest referring to Plesk documentation and help center for exact instructions, as it contains all necessary information. Here are some links:

[How to configure a local SmarterMail server for Plesk?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000360173)

[How to enable additional PHP version available in Plesk?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213930125)